# Getting "LeakSanitizer: detected memory leaks" with GCC, but Valgrind shows everything ok

Tags: c, memory-leaks, valgrind, dynamic-memory-allocation, singly-linked-list

I'm doing some basic tests to understand better how singly-linked-lists works in memory, as I have some doubts specific to the scope of malloc(), and why free() is not explicitly necessary in the code.

The problem starts when I compile my code, everything here seems fine, but when I run it, it shows the "LeakSanitizer: detected memory leaks" message.

I'm doing the compiling with `GCC version 10.1.0`

```
gcc linked.c -Wall -O2 -fsanitize=address -fno-omit-frame-pointer -march=skylake -flto -ggdb -o linked
```

Message after running my code:

```
==29248==ERROR: LeakSanitizer: detected memory leaks

Direct leak of 27 byte(s) in 3 object(s) allocated from:
    #0 0x7f924a2de9c7 in __interceptor_malloc (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasan.so.6+0xae9c7)
    #1 0x7f924b200aac in createNode /home/delok/linked.c:29
    #2 0x7f924b200aac in main /home/delok/linked.c:20
    #3 0x7f9249e51bf6 in __libc_start_main (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x21bf6)

SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: 27 byte(s) leaked in 3 allocation(s).
```

Something I can't understand is the fact that Valgrind tells me that everything its ok:

Valgrind command:

```
valgrind --leak-check=full -v ./linked
```

Valgrind output:

```
==29250==ASan runtime does not come first in initial library list; you should either link runtime to your application or manually preload it with LD_PRELOAD.
--29250-- REDIR: 0x4eec590 (libasan.so.6:free) redirected to 0x4c32cd0 (free)
==29250==
==29250== HEAP SUMMARY:
==29250==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==29250==   total heap usage: 0 allocs, 0 frees, 0 bytes allocated
==29250==
==29250== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==29250==
==29250== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
==29250== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Code:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>

 struct Node{

     unsigned short x : 5;
     struct Node *next;

 }__attribute__((packed));

 struct Node *head = NULL;

 // Definitions
 void createNode(int);

 int main(void)
 {

     for(int i = 0; i <= 3; ++i)
         createNode(i);

     return 0;

 }

 void createNode(int val)
 {

     struct Node *link = (struct Node *) malloc(sizeof(struct Node));

     link->x = val;
     link->next = head;
     head = link;

     printf("Node value: %d\n", link->x);
     printf("Node Address: %p\n", link);
     printf("Pointing to : %p\n", link->next);


 }
```

Best,

Comment: The loop `for(int i = 0; i <= 3; ++i)` creates **4** nodes, but the sanitizer only reports **3** allocations. Note that the `free()` is not strictly necessary because dynamically allocated memory is handed back to the system on program exit, but it's good practice to do the housekeeping yourself.

Comment: @WeatherVane, thanks for the answer, but a few questions, following good practices, which would be the correct way to free the allocated memory? Because in every call to createNode(),  malloc will allocate memory, so how could I do the cleaning when we refer to a malloc inside a function? And as I see maybe malloc is not the correct approach in this soluction right?

Comment: `malloc()` is fine for this job. To free the linked list, traverse it until you reach the `NULL` pointer link, putting each `next` member into a temporary variable and `free()` the node memory. You need the temporary variable because the `next` link won't be accessible after you `free()` the node. Practice the traversal with a `printlist()` function first.

Comment: I downloaded your code and build _two_ versions: one _with_ `-fsanitize=address` (e.g. `san`) and one _without_ (e.g. `val`). I ran `valgrind` on `val` and it complained. I ran `san` and it complained. When I ran `valgrind` on  `san`, the `libasan` code complained but `valgrind` _did_ not. Note that _both_ tools want to co-opt/redirect `malloc` et. al. so the two tools may be mutually exclusive

Comment: @WeatherVane, Thanks, really appreciate the advice, I'll be working on this the next days, stay safe!

Comment: @CraigEstey, that's good to know, I'll be studying more the GCC flags to fully understand the compatibility between tools. Thanks!

Comment: Try building without asan then running under Valgrind.